# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - Check if some column in MySQL are unique

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unique

I have a post with different titles/aka's. Now when a user adds a post, I wanna check if there is already a post with that title.

My table looks like this:

```
       +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
       | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
       +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
       | Titel    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
       | Alias1   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
       | Alias2   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
       | Alias3   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
       | Alias4   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
       +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And after the add-formular is send, i check the title like this:

```
include('./includes/database.php');
$sql = 'SELECT
            Titel
        FROM
            Posts
        WHERE
            Titel = \''.$titel.'\' OR 
            Alias1 = \''.$titel.'\' OR
            Alias2 = \''.$titel.'\' OR
            Alias3 = \''.$titel.'\' OR
            Alias4 = \''.$titel.'\' OR
            Titel = \''.$titel2.'\' OR 
            Alias1 = \''.$titel2.'\' OR
            Alias2 = \''.$titel2.'\' OR
            Alias3 = \''.$titel2.'\' OR
            Alias4 = \''.$titel2.'\' OR
            Titel = \''.$titel3.'\' OR 
            Alias1 = \''.$titel3.'\' OR
            Alias2 = \''.$titel3.'\' OR
            Alias3 = \''.$titel3.'\' OR
            Alias4 = \''.$titel3.'\' OR
            Titel = \''.$titel4.'\' OR 
            Alias1 = \''.$titel4.'\' OR
            Alias2 = \''.$titel4.'\' OR
            Alias3 = \''.$titel4.'\' OR
            Alias4 = \''.$titel4.'\' OR
            Titel = \''.$titel5.'\' OR 
            Alias1 = \''.$titel5.'\' OR
            Alias2 = \''.$titel5.'\' OR
            Alias3 = \''.$titel5.'\' OR
            Alias4 = \''.$titel5.'\'
        LIMIT
            1';
$result = $db->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die ('Can\'t send: '.$sql."<br />\nError: ".$db->error);
}
if ($result->num_rows) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $errorcounter++;
    $errors[$errorcounter] = '<p id="info" class="error">Already exists:<br><a href="./index.php?post='.$row['Titel'].'">'.$row['Titel'].'</a></p>';
}
```

But I think this is not the best way to do this, could someone say me how this can be done smart?

AND the most important: It doesn't work, i get this error:
**Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Comment: So why don't you check only the title, but also the aliases, however this can be achieved with a loop

Comment: Because an other user could has add a post with an other title. Something can be known as A or B or C. A user thinks the best title is C, an other thinks B is better. When a user has add a post and named it C and a other user adds the same and want name it A i have to check if it is there already. (Sry for my englisch, it is not my mother language..)

Comment: What does alias1,2,3,4 stand for, how they are used in your logic, and why they cannot be changed with one column only, not 4 columns

Comment: btw. where do you get the error message? It cannot be in this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit shorter, but still quite ineffective:

```
$sql = "SELECT
            Titel
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE
            Titel  IN ('".$titel."','".$titel1."','".$titel2."','".$titel3."','".$titel4."') OR 
            Alias1 IN ('".$titel."','".$titel1."','".$titel2."','".$titel3."','".$titel4."') OR 
            Alias2 IN ('".$titel."','".$titel1."','".$titel2."','".$titel3."','".$titel4."') OR 
            Alias3 IN ('".$titel."','".$titel1."','".$titel2."','".$titel3."','".$titel4."') OR 
            Alias4 IN ('".$titel."','".$titel1."','".$titel2."','".$titel3."','".$titel4."')
        LIMIT
            1";
```

You should consider putting aliases into separate table and linking it to `Posts` table. Thus you will have to check against only one field.

Comment: Thx, looks better at least :D But will it solve the error I'm getting?

Comment: @user2575625 Now, about that: `SELECT` statement cannot generate such error, there should be INSERT somewhere else with mismatched column/value caounts.

Comment: THX, now i found the problem! I was sure the error must be from the SELECT, but it was in my INSERT-Query..